# Redirect form to different URL based on select option element and get form details on email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am facing a problem in this code actually i want form details on email id when when submitted the form and its redirect to select option . i am trying below file name contactttry.php for form details is working file but ths code is not working for redirect.

i received form details on my email id but page not redirect to select tag so help me in this code or suggest a new code.
i am facing a problem in this code actually i want form details on email id when when submitted the form and its redirect to select option . i am trying below file name contactttry.php for form details is working file but ths code is not working for redirect.

i received form details on my email id but page not redirect to select tag so help me in this code or suggest a new code.

Thank you in advance

this is my Form code:

```
<form role="form" action="contactttry.php" class="contact-form" id="contact-form" method="post">
 <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="se1" NAME="section" onChange="SelectRedirect();">
    <Option value="">Select Section</option>
<Option value="PHP">PHP</option>
<Option value="ASP">ASP</option>
<Option value="MySQL">MySQL</option>
<Option value="JS">JavaScript</option>
<Option value="HTML">HTML</option>
  </select>
</div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                  <input type="email" class="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email" required >
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                  <input type="text" class="requiredField" placeholder="Mobile No." name="phone" id="phone" required>
                </div>
              </div>

              <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn-system btn-large" >Submit</button>
              <div id="success" style="color:#34495e;"></div>
            </form>
            <!-- End Contact Form -->
```

contactttry.php File:

```
<?php

$name              = $_POST['name'];
$email             = $_POST['email'];
$sub           = $_POST['subject'];
$phone                   = $_POST['phone'];
$intrest           = $_POST['message'];

$from = $txtemail; 
$from_name = $txtname; 
$to = "xyz@gmail.com"; 
$to_name = $name; `enter code here`
$subject = "Contact From IJLTEMAS"; 
$body ="
Name : ". $name."
Email: ".$email."
Phone: ".$phone."
Subject: ".$sub."
Message: ".$intrest."";
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))                   
mail($to, $subject, $body);
?>
<script>
function SelectRedirect(){
// ON selection of section this function will work
//alert( document.getElementById('s1').value);

switch(document.getElementById('s1').value)
{
case "PHP":
window.location="url1/";
break;

case "ASP":
window.location="url2/";
break;

case "MySQL":
window.location="url3/";
break;
case "JS":
window.location="url4/";
break;

case "HTML":
window.location="url/";
break;

/// Can be extended to other different selections of SubCategory //////
default:
window.location="homeurl/"; // if no selection matches then redirected to home page
break;
}// end of switch 
}
////////////////// 
</script>
```

Comment: Your select has an ID of `se1` but you're doing `document.getElementById("s1").value;` so it can't find your element.

Comment: hey Mark thank for suggestion . i changed se1 but till now it is not working

Comment: you have to give full path like this window.location = 'http://www.yahoo.com'

Answer (score 0):

```js
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("hi");
    $("#se1").change(function(){
      
switch($("#se1").value())
{
case "PHP":
window.location="url1/";
break;

case "ASP":
window.location="url2/";
break;

case "MySQL":
window.location="url3/";
break;
case "JS":
window.location="url4/";
break;

case "HTML":
window.location="url/";
break;

/// Can be extended to other different selections of SubCategory //////
default:
window.location="homeurl/"; // if no selection matches then redirected to home page
break;
}// end of switch 

 });
    });
////////////////// 
</script>
```

```html
<form role="form" action="contactttry.php" class="contact-form" id="contact-form" method="post">
 <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="se1" NAME="section" onChange="SelectRedirect();">
    <Option value="">Select Section</option>
<Option value="PHP">PHP</option>
<Option value="ASP">ASP</option>
<Option value="MySQL">MySQL</option>
<Option value="JS">JavaScript</option>
<Option value="HTML">HTML</option>
  </select>
</div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                  <input type="email" class="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email" required >
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                  <input type="text" class="requiredField" placeholder="Mobile No." name="phone" id="phone" required>
                </div>
              </div>

              <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn-system btn-large" >Submit</button>
              <div id="success" style="color:#34495e;"></div>
            </form>
            <!-- End Contact Form -->
```

Comment: thanks jothi i am trying your code but still problem are not solved. it is not redirecting...

Comment: first you check case working or not . alert inside the case

Comment: case are not working alert is shown till $(document).ready(function(){ when i put alert after $("#se1").change(function(){ then it is not working

Comment: i need a form when i click on submit button it perform two work first send the details of form to email id and second redirect to select box option which was select .

Comment: you just use normal form submit function

Answer (score 0):

form action="samepage.php"

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{


    //do email function here and then 

    switch ($_POST['section']) {

                    case "PHP":

                        header('Location:http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp');
                        exit();

                        break;

                            }

}
```